# Is it possible to include a nohup command inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, nohup

I have the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

until java -jar "MyApplication.jar"; do
    echo "---"
    date
    echo "Application crashed with exit code $?. Waiting to respawn..." >&2
    sleep 60
    echo "Respawning.." >&2
done
```

Which basically will relaunch the java application if it does not terminate with an exit code 0.

I currently invoke this program with:

```
nohup ./myapplication.sh &
```

Where `myapplication.sh` is the file which contains above script.

I invoke this program from a given xterm under X11. I would like to be sure that the program keeps running even if I close the xterm or even terminate the whole X11 session.

Two questions related to this:

1. Is it possible to include the nohup inside the script so I would just do: `./myapplication.sh &` or `./myapplication.sh`?
2. Is it possible to redirect the nohup output to a file named `myapplication_20191118_1723.out` (i.e. the name and a timestamp -format of the timestamp is not that relevant-) instead of the default `nohup.out`? That file shall contain both `std err` and `std out`.

Comment: BTW, your original code was logging the `$?` from `date`, not from `java`. Gotta be careful about order-of-operations.

Comment: As another aside, `nohup` only does any redirection *at all* if your program has handles on the TTY in the first place; if its handles are already on a file, `nohup` leaves them alone and doesn't open `nohup.out` at all.

Comment: Well spotted, I have corrected the order.

Comment: give `setsid` (run a program in a new session) chance. You can combine it with `nohup`.

Answer (score 2):

`nohup` doesn't actually do much of value.

- It redirects stdin from `/dev/null`, *if-and-only-if* it's initially connected to a TTY.
- It redirects stdout and stderr to `nohup.out`, *if-and-only-if* they're initially connected to a TTY.
- It declines to propagate HUP signals to its child processes.

All of these things you can simply do yourself, without using `nohup` at all. (Moreover, a *noninteractive* shell doesn't propagate HUPs by default in the first place!).

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# Redirect stdin from /dev/null, and stdout and stderr to a log file
# (not having TTY handles is part of how/why programs started with nohup can survive
# a terminal dying).
#
# Note that printf %(...)T is a bash 4.3 feature
# ...you may need to use date if your bash is older.
printf -v logfile_name 'myapplication_%(%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)T' -1
exec </dev/null >"$logfile_name" 2>&1

# ignore any HUP signals we receive (even though we shouldn't get any regardless)
trap '' HUP

# prevent the JVM from getting any handles on X11, which would be broken on exit
unset DISPLAY

until java -jar "MyApplication.jar"; do
    retval=$?
    echo "---" >&2
    date >&2
    echo "Application crashed with exit code $retval. Waiting to respawn..." >&2
    sleep 60
    echo "Respawning.." >&2
done
```

Comment: Yes I am specifically looking for the option of being able to disconnect the terminal, i.e. nohup

Comment: You don't *need* `nohup` to disconnect from the terminal. `exec </dev/null` disconnects stdin from the terminal. `exec >somefile.log 2>&1` disconnects stdout and stderr from the terminal. `disown`, another shell builtin, prevents propagation of HUP signals; combine those things, and you have everything `nohup` does, built into the shell itself; so `nohup` is effectively useless/needless overhead.

Comment: ...now, an *interactive* shell will also propagate HUP signals to children, which either using `nohup` or `disown -h` will suppress (the latter being a shell builtin), but a *noninteractive* interpreter (like one running a script!) doesn't do that in the first place.

Comment: So using `exec </dev/null >>nohup.out 2>&1` effectively makes the process launched independent of the terminal? I thought that the java process launched by this script would have as parent the shell ID from the terminal, and if you disconnect that effectively you are killing the parent (and hence the childs).

Comment: Killing a parent process does not automatically kill children; SIGTERMs don't propagate like that. Closing a terminal sends HUPs to processes with a handle on that terminal, but if you don't have a handle and you don't have a parent process that's explicitly propagating the signal, that's irrelevant.

Comment: So if I understood you right, if my Java process does not explicitly handle HUP signal (which it does not because I programmed it, it only handles SIGTERM) it will keep running even when the parent shell terminal where it was launched is killed. Is that correct?

Comment: I'd need to refer to docs re: the JVM's behavior to speak to that definitively. That said, if you're launching it from a noninteractive script that detaches from the TTY as this one does, I wouldn't even expect to receive (and need to handle) a HUP.

Comment: (That said, if your goal is to have a long-running background process, I'd generally advise using your operating system's process supervision system rather than rolling your own; that means launchd on MacOS, systemd on most modern Linux distros, etc; that generally buys you integration with your operating system's logging facilities, automatic startup on boot if you want it, service dependency support, and lots of other goodies).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know at all about HUP behaviour, I will test how JVM behaves with that. And regarding the advise I was planning to do that, to move into sort kind of userland supervision system. But I plan to do that a bit later once I have studied a bit systemd or whatever supervision is available in the user land space

Comment: Just to add that as you properly guessed, JVM does not handle by default SIGHUP, so as my program does not handle it either, it keeps running even when the parent shell it was launched from is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: **yes**, of course you can!

How and why, I hear you say?

What if I need to run a program that does not play well with the console, e.g. the KDE file explorer, [Dolphin](https://apps.kde.org/en-gb/dolphin/)?

When I run that from the command line and it prints out streams of internal Qt low level messages and mostly (if it's working correctly) these are meaningless and can be ignored. There are sometimes so many that they tend to make the terminal useless.

The following would be a way to stop that happening.  And (if properly configured) could also be used to make it send the terminal output `STDOUT` to a named pipe, connected to a TCP server by using programs like [netcat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) or the more capable [socat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat).

This example is great if you want to run a noisy program from your login script.

```bash
function shush () { \
 QC="$1"; \
 shift; \
 nohup  "${QC}" $* >/dev/null 2>&1 & \
 disown; \
}
```

This make use of the bash `function`, `alias` and `job control` features.
How this works:

- We capture the 1st command parameter into `${QC}` as that will be the command we want to run later
- `shift` is used to drop the 1st paramter so it does not get passed again
- `nohup` is used to disconnect `stdin` and `stdout` from the app
- `2>&1` is used to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`
- `>/dev/null` *pipes* `stdout` into `/dev/null` to get swallowed into nothingness.
- The expansion of the string `${QC}` is the command we will run, the quotes are there just in case the path has spaces in it.
- `$*` expands all the remaining parameters, the same as `$1 $2 $3 ....`
- the ampersand `&` makes the command into a background job
- `disown` disassociates the last job from the terminal that started the job

[`nohup`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) would normally create a file `nohup.out`, so the pipe to /dev/null prevent that.

[`disown`](https://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x8244.html) is (usually) a shell built in statement and works by making the last background command (aka job) immune to signals such as [HUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) coming from the terminal.  That means closing the terminal will not close the program.

BTW: I use this to allow me to run multiple GUI commands in Windows under WSL!

Now we can do...

```bash
> shush dolphin
```

Perhaps we would want to use it in a terminal too, we don't want to keep typing shush.

Then do this in `~/.bash_aliases`

```
alias dolphin='shush dolphin'
```

Now we can do both, the now shushed `dolphin` command works the same in a terminal or in a script, with or without command line parameters.

Ahh, I hear you say, but what if we need to undo that and "unshush" it, e.g. to use the `--help` command line option?

There are at least two ways.
Quick and dirty, just bypass the alias using `which`

```bash
$(which dolphin) --help
```

Another way would be to modify the `shush ()` function/script to extract the 2nd parameter (or scan all of them) and check if it is `--noshush` and/or has other parameters that need the terminal and act accordingly, but lets make that homework for the reader ;)

Comment: (1) You don't need all the backslashes in that function -- inside a function definition newlines are perfectly valid unescaped. (2) `$*` is buggy -- it changes `"argument one" "argument two"` to `argument one argument two`; to avoid that, `"$@"` should be used instead. (3) `function funcname() {` merges the 1980s ksh syntax `function funcname {` and the standardized-since-1991 POSIX sh syntax `funcname() {` in a way that's incompatible with **both** legacy ksh and POSIX.

Comment: (4) See my answer -- `nohup` isn't actually doing anything here that bash itself can't do built-in. (5) `$(which dolphin) --help` is _much_ slower than `command dolphin --help` (as `which` is an external executable, not part of the shell, in bash -- note that this is different in zsh -- and use of `$()` forks off a subshell, which has its own performance cost); the `which` use also adds bugs in some weird corner cases (like if the directory name the `dolphin` command is found in contains whitespace).